# Is there a reason checksc50 is saying my code isn't working 100% in pset1 credit?

Tags: c, computer-science, cs50

So for some reason some of the credit card numbers are working as expected and some aren't (at least in CS50's eyes) To me it all looks fine.  Here is what checkCS50 says:

```
:) credit.c exists

:) credit.c compiles

:( identifies 378282246310005 as AMEX
    expected "AMEX\n", not "INVALID\n"

:( identifies 371449635398431 as AMEX
    expected "AMEX\n", not "INVALID\n"

:( identifies 5555555555554444 as MASTERCARD
    expected "MASTERCARD\n", not "INVALID\n"

:( identifies 5105105105105100 as MASTERCARD
    expected "MASTERCARD\n", not "INVALID\n"

:) identifies 4111111111111111 as VISA

:( identifies 4012888888881881 as VISA
    expected "VISA\n", not "INVALID\n"

:) identifies 4222222222222 as VISA

:) identifies 1234567890 as INVALID (invalid length, checksum, identifying digits)

:) identifies 369421438430814 as INVALID (invalid identifying digits)

:) identifies 4062901840 as INVALID (invalid length)

:) identifies 5673598276138003 as INVALID (invalid identifying digits)

:) identifies 4111111111111113 as INVALID (invalid checksum)

:) identifies 4222222222223 as INVALID (invalid checksum)

:) identifies 3400000000000620 as INVALID (AMEX identifying digits, VISA/Mastercard length)

:) identifies 430000000000000 as INVALID (VISA identifying digits, AMEX length)
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
long creditLong = get_long("What is your credit card number? "); // Get the number
char creditArray[20]; // Convert to array
snprintf(creditArray, sizeof(creditArray), "%ld", creditLong);

long creditLength = strlen(creditArray); // Get length
// printf("creditLength is %ld\n", creditLength);

int sumFirst = 0; // Checksum variables
int sumSecond = 0;

for (int i = creditLength - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2)
{                                     // For loops to get sum
    int digit = creditArray[i] - '0'; // ASCII to Int value ('0' = 48 in ASCII)
    sumFirst += digit * 2;
}

for (int j = creditLength - 1; j >= 0; j -= 2)
{
    int digit = creditArray[j] - '0';
    sumSecond += digit;
}
int checkSum = sumFirst + sumSecond;


char luhnTest[10]; // Convert to array
snprintf(luhnTest, sizeof(luhnTest), "%d", checkSum);
int testLength = strlen(luhnTest); // Get length of card number

if (luhnTest[testLength - 1] == '0')
{ // Start of If Statement

    switch (creditLength)
    {
        case 15:
            if (creditArray[0] == '3' && (creditArray[1] == '4' || creditArray[1] == '7'))
            {
                printf("AMEX\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
            break;

        case 13:
            if (creditArray[0] == '4')
            {
                printf("VISA\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
            break;

        case 16:
            if (creditArray[0] == '4')
            {
                printf("VISA\n");
            }
            else if (creditArray[0] == '5' && (creditArray[1] == '1' || creditArray[1] == '2' || creditArray[1] == '3' ||
                                               creditArray[1] == '4' || creditArray[1] == '5'))
            {
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
            break;

        default:
            printf("INVALID\n");
    }
} // End of IF Statement
else
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run and debug the failed testcases locally?

Comment: What do you mean by that? It compiles successfully

Comment: The ones that fail- they actually have a checksum that does not end with 0, but according to CS50 they are valid

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. You have bugs in your code. The good news is you know exactly what is failing since it shows you the test case. Shouldn't be too hard to figure out what's not working from that.

Comment: Is a long on your system big enough to hold credit card numbers?

Comment: Don't read the credit card number as a number. Just read it as a string directly.

Comment: You're right @Barmar reading it as a long and then converting overcomplicates the code.  I'll try that thanks

Comment: The thing is take for example: :( identifies 4012888888881881 as VISA expected "VISA\n", not "INVALID\n"   >  The checksum here is actually invalid

Comment: Your Luhn algorithm is apparently wrong. For the first failing number, it's calculating 69.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Joseph F, If wanting to stay with numeric input, use `long long` as `long` may not be _long_ enough for a CC #.

Comment: @Barmar it is actually 69 though...

Comment: Take another look at the description for Luhn's Algorithm and compare your code to it. https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/1/credit/ You're missing a vital step. Here's one that works for the first number that failed. I didn't test the others so it's possible it isn't quite right either, but the step you missed is adding up the digits of the numbers that are multiplied by two and not the numbers themselves. https://godbolt.org/z/e1G4Tz1z4

Comment: But *don't* stay with numeric input.  It is semantically wrong, and it's harder to work with in this case to boot.  "Credit card numbers" are not really numbers.  They are *digit sequences*, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @RetiredNinja you are correct! If say one of the products is 14, I need to add 1 + 4... Thanks!! My issue was misreading the algorithm, not the implementation.  I will though change the input to a string to make the code more concise and semantically correct

Comment: If you input to `long` and convert to a string you'll lose any leading zeros.

Comment: Ok but a credit card with a leading zero is either way invalid according to my program... @WeatherVane

Comment: @JohnBollinger the reason I started with get_long was to avoid inputs that contained spaces or letters, as I felt that would it make it harder for me to sort, instead of just getting a number, and then converting it to an array.

Comment: @JosephF how will you know? You might false card type digits that aren't the leading digits. Card and phone "numbers" are not integers. They are digit strings.

Comment: @JosephF, suppose you take a valid VISA number and prepend 0.  The resulting input should be considered invalid, but if your program otherwise works correctly then losing the leading digit will cause it to instead report the input as a valid VISA number.

Answer (score 0):

I did not peruse all of the comments, but the gist of your issue is in the calculation of the hash total amounts for the even digits.

```
for (int i = creditLength - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2)
{                                     // For loops to get sum
    int digit = creditArray[i] - '0'; // ASCII to Int value ('0' = 48 in ASCII)
    sumFirst += digit * 2;
}
```

If you read through the methodology of the Luhn algorithm, you will note that if the product of the digit being doubled is greater than "9", the value of "9" is supposed to be subtracted from the doubled digit.

FYI, following is a link to the Wikipedia discussion of the algorithm.

"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm"

With that following is the refactored block of code.

```
for (int i = creditLength - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2)
{
    // For loops to get sum
    int digit = creditArray[i] - '0'; // ASCII to Int value ('0' = 48 in ASCII)
    if (digit > 4)                      /* As per the Luhn algorithm specs  */
        sumFirst += (digit * 2 - 9);
    else
        sumFirst += digit * 2;
}
```

With that bit of refactoring, following was a test of a few of your examples.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CheckLuhn/bin/Release$ ./CheckLuhn 
What is your credit card number? 378282246310005
AMEX
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CheckLuhn/bin/Release$ ./CheckLuhn 
What is your credit card number? 5555555555554444
MASTERCARD
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CheckLuhn/bin/Release$ ./CheckLuhn 
What is your credit card number? 4012888888881881
VISA
```

Your checksum algorithm was not properly handling the conditional doubling process for any digit of "5" or higher, which is why many of the tests incorrectly failed, but the example of "4111111111111111" passed because all of the digits were "4" or less.

The take-away here, is be thorough in your review of testing algorithms when building code so that the code agrees with the test.